# Outputting four rows based on two categories each with a boolean

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table of users:

```
USER ID   |   GENDER   |   VOTE
----------------------------------    
1             Male         Yes
2             Female       No
3             Male         No
4             Male         Yes
5             Female       Yes
```

How can I write a query that outputs the genders by their vote breakdown:

```
GENDER   |    YES    |   NO
----------------------------------
Male          2          1
Female        1          1
```

Is this possible to do it in SQL or should I use PHP to build these totals?

Any help is appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This type of transformation of data is known as pivot.  MySQL doesn't have a PIVOT function but you can replicate the function by using an aggregate function with a CASE expression:

```
select gender,
  sum(case when vote = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) Yes,
  sum(case when vote = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) No
from yourtable
group by gender;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13c6b/2).  Since you are using MySQL you could also use the [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) control-flow operator:

```
select gender,
  sum(if(vote = 'Yes', 1, 0)) Yes,
  sum(if(vote = 'No', 1, 0)) No
from yourtable
group by gender;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/13c6b/4). These both give a result:

```
| GENDER | YES | NO |
|--------|-----|----|
| Female |   1 |  1 |
|   Male |   2 |  1 |
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't realize you can take the sum of a case statement. Thank you for your thorough and very clear answer :)

Comment: Since you are using MySQL, you even "simplify" it further, to `sum(vote = 'Yes') Yes, sum(vote = 'No') No` because in MySQL `TRUE` is evaluated/stored as `1` and `FALSE` as `0`.

Comment: Congrat for the 100k :) , what it feels now ? :)